# CoreData schema evolution with Simperium

Tags: simperium

How does Simperium handle schema evolution with CoreData? It looked like schema evolution is not currently supported according to the docs, so are there techniques to handle it in the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any schema changes that can be handled by Core Data's lightweight migration can also be handled by Simperium. Currently, other changes like renaming or removing attributes can work with Simperium as long as you're properly handling the local migration on users' devices.

This works because Simperium's schemas are dynamic by default. What's not yet exposed is a way to lock in a particular version of a schema and map this to a corresponding version of your app's model. We're testing this internally; if you need it, please get in touch.

Comment: Automatic support for lightweight migration is great news.  Thanks!