# Simperium loses data when adding a new property to an entity

Tags: ios, core-data, migration, simperium

I've read [in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186379/coredata-schema-evolution-with-simperium) that Simperium should be able to handle Core Data lightweight migrations fine. However, I'm currently struggling with the simple case of adding an (optional) property to an existing entity.

To make the issue a bit easier to follow, let's go through an example. Let's say that my previous app version is 1.0 and a new version 1.1 introduces a new property `foo` on a Core Data entity.

Now, let's consider this scenario:

1. Device A and B both run version 1.0 and are attached to the same Simperium sync account, both up-to-date.
2. Device A upgrades to version 1.1, the property is created in the data base, and the user adds some data to the new `foo` property. This data is correctly synced to the Simperium backend and `foo` is visible in the web data browser.
3. Device B (still on version 1.0, i.e. without `foo`) syncs with Simperium. At this point I see `Simperium warning: applyDiff for a member that doesn't exist`, which is understandable because `foo` does not exist. Everything still expected and fine here.
4. Now device B upgrades to 1.1. When starting the app for the first time, Core Data creates the new `foo` column. However, now that the `foo` property is there, Simperium still does not pull its data from the backend, so devices A and B don't see the same data for `foo`!

I understand why this happens (Simperium has discarded the change the first time, because the property wasn't there yet, and then doesn't apply the same change again later when it could). However, I think this is quite problematic and effectively makes even the simplest changes to the data model very risky. Am I missing anything here? What would be a safe way to add a new property to an entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry it took us a while to reply (please, by all means, feel free to open an issue on Github, anytime!).

For the time being, there are few caveats when it comes to Migrations.

I've filed [this issue](https://github.com/Simperium/simperium-ios/issues/518), to properly handle the New Attributes scenario, and [this issue](https://github.com/Simperium/simperium-ios/issues/480) to deal with attribute renames.

Right now, although the protocol is resilient, and sync'ing should recover on its own (in the eventuality in which something happens, and a client goes off sync, ie. migrations), an attribute rename will cause glitches.

For now, i'm afraid that the easiest // safest way to deal migrations, would be to create another bucket, that would have the desired set of attributes.

Sorry about this inconvenience, we'll be iterating over this!

Comment: Thank you Jorge, as always! This was not time-critical for me, so no worries. I've written here instead of github, because I thought you'd prefer it (it says so in the documentation) and I was not 100% sure if this was an issue with the library rather than me doing/understanding something wrong.

Comment: Actually, I never had the expectation that renaming attributes would work without problems. However, I was surprised that *adding* new attributes caused problems (and I think this is by far the more serious problem of the two). Renaming stuff in DBs is almost always a problem and even more so in a distributed environment, so I guess most people would understand (it should be documented, though).